# Oracle Forms and Reports 11G R2 installation (Win 7 64bit)

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, middleware

I am trying to install Oracle Forms and Reports in Win7 (64 bits) and receive the exception below:

[image: Oracle Forms and Reports installation Wizard - Step 5]

Are two exceptions:

INST-07404: Error in validating Oracle home
INST-07248: Error in validating Middleware home location

What am I doing wrong?

I have already installed and running the Weblogic 12c:

[image: configuration screen]

Answer (score 2):

> The pre-requisite is to have Weblogic Server 11gR1 (10.3.5 or 10.3.6) installed prior to
>   installing Oracle Forms and Report 11gR2.

When you install Weblogic Server 10.3.5 or 10.3.6, it will create the middleware home location in your computer. So, your first step would be to install Weblogic Server 10.3.x, available for download [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/middleware/weblogic/downloads/wls-main-097127.html).

More information on installation guideline visit [this](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23104_01/download_readme_cr2/download_readme_cr2.htm).

Comment: Hi @Annjawn. I have already installed and running the Weblogic (12c).

Comment: Then the middleware directory should typically be `C:\Oracle\Middleware`. I see that you have selected a directory as `C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home...`. Also, try un-installing WLS 12c and installing WLS 11g 10.3.5 or 10.3.6.

Comment: Hi @Annjawn, thanks for the support.

I removed WLS 12c. With the 10.3.6 installed, I received another exception:

INST-07408: Unable to install or configure the product on a 32-bit JVM on a 64-bit machine

Comment: download 64 bit Java 1.6 JDK, Install it. Now go to My Computer -> Right Click Properties-> create environment variable JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jre6. Also, you will need to download and install the Generic WLS 10.3.6 (wls1036_generic.jar) because that is the only one compatible with 64 Bit machines. The wls1306...exe files are only 32 bit compatible.

Comment: For Annjawn's installation use: java -jar wls1036_generic.jar command.